# How can I bind a function key to emit a color code?

Tags: bash, colors, readline

I'm making a terminal recording and I would like to change the terminal foreground color to emphasize certain parts (such as certain command line arguments) in the recording.

How can I map a function key to emit a color code in bash/readline?

I can bind to other things like the arrow keys using `bind '"\e[21~":"\e[A"'`, so I think doing something like `bind '"\e[21~":"\e[[31m"'` should emit a color code and change the fg color.

It doesn't. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind a key to a string like `\e[A` then this key emits this string which in turn is again parsed by the readline library and interpreted (in this case to mean "up" which is then pointing to the function `previous-history`).  The string is never printed to the terminal.

So if you want to print something, you need to bind a key to a function which prints something arbitrary (your ANSI color escape sequence).  I'm not aware of such a readline function because it doesn't make much sense if you think it through.  The problem is that readline has no notion (no internal model) of colored characters.  Readline is for raw characters only, without character styles.  Switching the color, entering some visible characters, then using cursor keys to edit already typed (maybe colored, maybe standard) characters -- stuff like this will lead to redraws of the complete line.  In that process the colors will be eradicated quickly (because readline doesn't really know about them).

So I guess what you want just isn't possible.  It is a feature not supported by readline and which you cannot simply add to it (correctly) from the outside without breaking things.

Comment: Ah. Thank you for pointing out the mistake in my mental model. I would have been happy with color that persist until the next redraw but it does seem like this isn't easily done.